# Unable to build entity manager factory org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

UsuariosEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios", schema = "public", catalog = "pruebapractico1")
public class UsuariosEntity{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private Date creationdate;
    private RolesEntity rolesByRoleid;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastname")
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "creationdate")
    public Date getCreationdate() {
        return creationdate;
    }

    public void setCreationdate(Date creationdate) {
        this.creationdate = creationdate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UsuariosEntity that = (UsuariosEntity) o;

        if (username != null ? !username.equals(that.username) : that.username != null) return false;
        if (password != null ? !password.equals(that.password) : that.password != null) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;
        if (lastname != null ? !lastname.equals(that.lastname) : that.lastname != null) return false;
        if (email != null ? !email.equals(that.email) : that.email != null) return false;
        if (creationdate != null ? !creationdate.equals(that.creationdate) : that.creationdate != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = username != null ? username.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (password != null ? password.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (lastname != null ? lastname.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (creationdate != null ? creationdate.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "roleid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public RolesEntity getRolesByRoleid() {
        return rolesByRoleid;
    }

    public void setRolesByRoleid(RolesEntity rolesByRoleid) {
        this.rolesByRoleid = rolesByRoleid;
    }
}
```

RoleEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles", schema = "public", catalog = "pruebapractico1")
public class RolesEntity implements Serializable{
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        RolesEntity that = (RolesEntity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (description != null ? !description.equals(that.description) : that.description != null) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>Entity.RolesEntity</class>
    <class>Entity.UsuariosEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pruebapractico1"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="james1994"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Libreries

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
byte-buddy-1.6.6.jar
classmate-1.3.0.jar
dom4j.1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.10.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
javax.persistence-2.1.1.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
persistence-api-1.0.2.jar
postgresql-9.4.1211.jre7.jar
```

When I call the entityManagerFactory with the same name that the persistence unit have the program show an exception related to the entityManager. 
I try a lot of things that I don't have good results.

The call at EntityManagerFactory it's the next:

```
EntityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit");
```

I don't have any idea what is cause the problem. I attach in this query part of the code with my entities, the persistence file and the libreries that I have in the project.

Thanks for your help.

Stack Trace

```
Context Path:/Prueba4practico1_war_exploded
Servlet Path:/User
Path Info:null
Query String:null
Stack Trace
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
Servlet.UserServlet.doPost(UserServlet.java:26)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$36(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$40(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1706)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$40(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1706)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$40(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1706)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$40(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1706)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$40(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1706)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:211)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:809)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace in the question

Comment: I add the Stack trace.